# Android Encrypt with ADB install? TWRP CarbonROM

Tags: adb, encryption

I have the following problem: I have CarbonROM 8.0 and the default /data full encryption does not work. Now I want to set it up with the ADB {Android-Bridge}... à la: `adb shell recovery --set_filesystem_encryption=on`

does anyone know which commands I would have to enter? alternatively, I could use the terminal in TWRP 3.4.0.0. my device: Maple, Sony Xperia XZ Premium 8242
Thank you very much.

Comment: I have removed the duplicate German part, please use English only here on stacks xchange.

Comment: you need to repair your fstab, compare userdata flags with stock ROM